# Does Away3D 4x require Flash player 11 or will it run in previous flash players - e.g. 10, 9 without the GPU hooks?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d, flash-player-11

Does Away3D 4x require Flash player 11 or will it run in previous flash players - e.g. 10, 9 without the GPU availability through Stage3D?

If not, are there any libraries that can?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stage3D is only available in Flash Player 11.

Away3D 4 Broomstick requires Flash Player 11; however, clearly previous versions of Away3D would operate in previous versions of Flash Player.

If you're looking for greatest compatibility across Flash Player versions, you should use an older version.

I'm unsure about the fail-over of other 3D engines, such as Alternativa or Flare3D.